# Query last N values of json value in postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, json, database, postgresql

i have json file like this in postgresql:

```
{
    "timestamp":[
        "2020-01-05 01:05:45",
        "2020-01-07 05:58:02",
        "2020-01-05 23:58:51",
        "2020-01-06 04:38:36",
        "2020-01-07 08:55:28",
        "2020-01-06 10:59:32",
        "2020-01-07 16:37:26",
        "2020-01-07 17:12:57",
        "2020-01-06 20:36:14",
        "2020-01-06 10:11:29"
    ],
    "value":[9,66,20,43,59,76,22,10,20,62]
}
```

i want to query last N values of timestamp and value. if N = 2 we have:

```
[("2020-01-06 20:36:14","2020-01-06 10:11:29"),(20,62)]
```

Comment: @Nick thanks for editing

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres 12, you can use [`jsonb_path_query_array()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH-OPERATORS) for this.

Assuming that your json payload is stored in column `js` of `mytable`, the following query gives you the last 3 elements of each of the two arrays.

```
select
    t.*,
    jsonb_path_query_array(
        t.js -> 'timestamp', 
        '$[$.size() - 3 to $.size() - 1]'
    ) last_3_timestamps,
    jsonb_path_query_array(
        t.js -> 'value',     
       '$[$.size() - 3 to $.size() - 1]'
    ) last_3_values
from mytable t
```

JSON path expression `'$[$.size() - 3 to $.size() - 1]'` filters the last 3 items. `size()` gets the array size, while array indexes start at `0`, so `$.size() - 1` is the index of the last element of the array. If there are less than 3 elements, all elements are returned.

Comment: thanks a lot. your answer was very helpful to me. @GMB

Comment: my data was in json format not jsonb so the below query works for me:

`select
jsonb_path_query_array((mycolumn -> 'timestamp')::jsonb,'$[$.size() - 3 to $.size() - 1]') last_3_timestamps,
jsonb_path_query_array((mycolumn -> 'value')::jsonb,'$[$.size() - 3 to $.size() - 1]') last_3_values
from mytable;`